# (Manipulação de arquivos em python) Estou com dificuldade para verificar a validação do ip, como posso continuar o código?

Tags: python-3.x

Um programa que leia um arquivo texto contendo uma lista de endereços IP e
armazene em um vetor os endereços inválidos de IP.

Arquivo de entrada:

```
200.135.80.9
192.168.1.1
8.35.67.74
257.32.4.5
85.345.1.2
1.2.3.4
9.8.234.5
192.168.0.256
```

Saída:

```
["257.32.4.5", "85.345.1.2", "9.8.234.5", "192.168.0.256"]
```

Meu código:

```py
ip = open('endereços.txt','r')
line = []
line = ip.read().split('\n')

#Estrutura incompleta
if 0 > ip[0] > 255:
    print(ip[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplificando esse código:
ip_validos=[]

```
for ip in open("endereços.txt"):
      #condição...validar ips
      ip_validos = ip_validos + [ip.replace("\n",'')]
      print(ip.replace("\n",'')) #replace remove os espaço em branco
```

#lista de ip

```
print(ip_validos)
```

Não foi especificado qual classe de ip sera verificada

```
Classe A    
Classe B    
Classe C
```

Comment: no caso , foram esses que tão como saída

Comment: você tem alguma ideia de como seria essa saída?

Comment: legal, pode usar o import socket  e  chamar a função para verificar   ...  socket.inet_aton(ip.replace("\n",'')) e tratar usando exception , dentro do try a lista dos ip validos e no except os que não são varidos.

Comment: tá bem, vou tentar !